# Compare dates in XSLT 1.0 which has yyyymmdd format

Tags: date, xslt, compare, xslt-1.0, date-comparison

Can some one help how we can compare dates which has yyyymmdd format in xslt 1.0?

I think date which has yyyymmdd is numerically comparable because for example

today -> 20170809 is 
always less than days after today like 20170810,20170811 and 20170812 
always greater than days before today like 20170808,20170807 and 20170806

Can someone help on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Flynn1179 I have restored the XSLT/XSLT 1.0 tags, because in other languages the comparison could be alphabetical or even calendrical.

Answer (score 1):

If by "compare" you mean getting a result of "less than",  "greater than" or "equal", then yes, your proposition is correct: a later date will always be numerically greater than an earlier one.